# how do I report a kernel bug to linux developers mailing list?

Tags: linux, usb, kernel

I have a problem (bug) with linux kernel , specifically bcm6xx  usb code on bcm6318 cpu.
how do I post this to linux-usb mailing list? I have no experience with mailing lists

Comment: Please don't resubmit questions that were closed without significantly revamping them. 

[Original Post](https://superuser.com/questions/1544091/reporting-bug-and-using-linux-usb-mailing-list)

Comment: @Meow_ly sorry I thought they were permenantly closed !

Comment: http://www.linux-usb.org/mailing.html tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: @DavidPostill I found that page , but still don't know how to send the email describing my problem to the mailing list, what address should I send to ?

Comment: Subscribe to the list. It will return instructions on how to use the list.

Comment: http://cfpm.org/docs/majordomo/UM.txt

Comment: Once you are subscribed to the list you can send "help" to the list to get a list of commands to can use.

Comment: there is a list archive at https://marc.info/?l=linux-usb which you can search ...